# Error with ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2

I used WCF to host a .svc service to retrieve data from MySQL (both on local host), I have written a class to consume the service on Android, using ksoap2 version 3.1.1 and IP 10.0.3.2 for Geny Motion to access local host

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class KetNoiWebService {
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String MAIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://10.0.3.2:7741/ToaDoServiceHost.svc";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IToaDo/GetAllToaDo";

    private static final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapObject request) {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        return envelope;
    }

    private static final HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE() {
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(MAIN_REQUEST_URL, 60000);

        return ht;
    }

    public static int getAllToaDoTuWebService() {
        int count = 1;

        String methodname = "GetAllToaDo";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodname);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();

        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject resultsString = (SoapObject) envelope
                    .bodyIn;
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)resultsString.getProperty(0);

            count = result.getPropertyCount();

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception q) {
            q.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

and call that class on an Activity

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class KhuSanXuatActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_khusanxuat);

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.webservicecount))
        .setText((KetNoiWebService.getAllToaDoTuWebService()));
    }


}
```

**activity_khusanxuat.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="San pham dang co trong kho:" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text=" - Bap u chua: " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="100 "
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="cuon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text=" - Phan ga: " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="50 "
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="tan" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Du toan san luong:" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text=" - Bap u chua" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="    + Ngay thu hoach du kien: " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:text="01/07/2014"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="    + San luong du kien: " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="200 "
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="cuon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text=" - Phan ga" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="    + Ngay thu hoach du kien: " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20/07/2014"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="    + San luong du kien: " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="150 "
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="tan" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webservicecount"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and it gets error

```
05-28 14:23:37.082: W/System.err(2574): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-28 14:23:37.086: W/System.err(2574):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
05-28 14:23:37.086: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
05-28 14:23:37.090: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
05-28 14:23:37.090: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-28 14:23:37.094: W/System.err(2574):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-28 14:23:37.098: W/System.err(2574):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
05-28 14:23:37.098: W/System.err(2574):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
05-28 14:23:37.102: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
05-28 14:23:37.106: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-28 14:23:37.106: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
05-28 14:23:37.106: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
05-28 14:23:37.110: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-28 14:23:37.110: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
05-28 14:23:37.110: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
05-28 14:23:37.110: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
05-28 14:23:37.110: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
05-28 14:23:37.114: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
05-28 14:23:37.114: W/System.err(2574):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
05-28 14:23:37.114: W/System.err(2574):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:126)
05-28 14:23:37.118: W/System.err(2574):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:185)
05-28 14:23:37.118: W/System.err(2574):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
05-28 14:23:37.118: W/System.err(2574):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
05-28 14:23:37.118: W/System.err(2574):     at com.example.mapdemo.KetNoiWebService.getAllToaDoTuWebService(KetNoiWebService.java:47)
05-28 14:23:37.122: W/System.err(2574):     at com.example.mapdemo.KhuSanXuatActivity.onCreate(KhuSanXuatActivity.java:16)
05-28 14:23:37.126: W/System.err(2574):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-28 14:23:37.126: W/System.err(2574):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-28 14:23:37.126: W/System.err(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-28 14:23:37.126: W/System.err(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/System.err(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/System.err(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/System.err(2574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/System.err(2574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/System.err(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/System.err(2574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/System.err(2574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/System.err(2574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/System.err(2574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/System.err(2574):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 14:23:37.130: W/ResourceType(2574): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
05-28 14:23:37.134: D/AndroidRuntime(2574): Shutting down VM
05-28 14:23:37.134: W/dalvikvm(2574): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6284288)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapdemo/com.example.mapdemo.KhuSanXuatActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at com.example.mapdemo.KhuSanXuatActivity.onCreate(KhuSanXuatActivity.java:16)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-28 14:23:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     ... 11 more
05-28 14:23:41.590: I/Process(2574): Sending signal. PID: 2574 SIG: 9
```

I have tested the URL on Geny Motion browser, I also wrote a Java console application and consumed successfully the service using above class, anyone help me please, thanks so much!

**`http://localhost:7741/ToaDoServiceHost.svc?wsdl`**

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="ToaDoService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://sang-pc:7741/ToaDoServiceHost.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://sang-pc:7741/ToaDoServiceHost.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://sang-pc:7741/ToaDoServiceHost.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BogacaServices"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IToaDo_GetAllToaDo_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetAllToaDo"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IToaDo_GetAllToaDo_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetAllToaDoResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IToaDo">
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllToaDo">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IToaDo/GetAllToaDo" message="tns:IToaDo_GetAllToaDo_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IToaDo/GetAllToaDoResponse" message="tns:IToaDo_GetAllToaDo_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IToaDo" type="tns:IToaDo">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllToaDo">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IToaDo/GetAllToaDo" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ToaDoService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IToaDo" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IToaDo">
<soap:address location="http://sang-pc:7741/ToaDoServiceHost.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: did you even try to read the error log and research some information before asking here?

Comment: So sorry because I haven't known Async so far, I will read more clearly next times, thanks

Comment: I hope you got my point. Try to examine first the source of the problem instead of just posting it online. There are tons of duplicate questions about this and many other common mistakes. Have a happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class DoInBack extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String res = "";
            try {

                res=KetNoiWebService.getAllToaDoTuWebService();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+result, 1).show();
                        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.webservicecount))
        .setText(result);

        }
    }
```

and write below line in onCreate

```
new DoInBack().execute("");
```

thats it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do all your network operations.

Your network operation can take a lot of time and the UI would get unresponsive if it is done on the main UI thread. And if your UI freezes for a long time, the app might get killed by the OS.

Thus Android 4+ makes it mandatory to use a background thread to perform network operations.

Put the code to do the network activity inside **`doInBackground()`** and all the AsyncTask using **`execute()`**.

Here is how your AsyncTask would look like :

```
private class SendMail extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
     protected void doInBackground() {
        sendEmail();
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    //called when the background task makes any progress
 }

  protected void onPreExecute() {
     //called before doInBackground() is started
 }
 protected void onPostExecute() {
     //called after doInBackground() has finished 
 }
  }
```

And you can call it anywhere using **`new SendMail().execute("");`**

Answer (score 0):

You should not call web services in Main Thread(UI Thread).
You should use Services or AsyncTask for doing the same